# Why not catch up parshas right away?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, torah-reading, chutz-laaretz

This week, the parsha in chutz la'aretz is Parshat Shmini and in Israel, the parsha is Tazria-Mitzora because of the 8th day of Pesach in Chu"l falling on Shabbat. But why do they not read Tazria this week in Israel and Mitzorah next week with us in Chu"l reading Tazria-Mitzora next week to catch up? Why wait a whole month until the next double-parsha?

Comment: And not only do we not use Tazria-Metzora to align, but we don't do it with Acharei-Kedoshim either.

Comment: Wait till you see next year's schedule...